# How do I change the directory in Git Bash with Git for Windows?

Tags: linux, git, terminal, git-bash

How would I change to the directory `C:/Users/myname/project name` in Git Bash?

Comment: `cd 'THAT_DIRECTORY'` ??

Comment: no `That (space) Directory`.

Comment: use underscores in your project name, instead of spaces it will save you trouble

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
cd /c/users/myname/project\ name
```

Beware that `ls /`, or typing `cd /` followed by Tab-completion, might not show the existence of this folder, but `cd /c` will still work. Also note that `pwd` (to print the current working directory) might show something like `/bin`, but this might not be the actual working folder for commands such as `git clone`, which might use the folder from which Git Bash was started.

Comment: Or `cd "/c/Users/myname/project name"`

Comment: I know this is old, but mine only seems to work when I use (" "), why is this?

Comment: a subset of this problem is to simply change drives; whereas in MS-DOS one uses a separate command `d:` to change to drive **d**, in **Git Bash** one uses the `cd` command thus:  `cd /d` to change to the **d** drive.

Comment: Wow, I thought this answer did not apply to my situation, until I finally tried... I edited to add some details, I hope that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

If the you know how many levels up from your current working directory, you could use `cd ../project/name` to avoid writing the entire directory path.

The `..` represents moving 1 directory up.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use quotes in your directory name, or the short version of the filename.

You can find the short version of the file name by issuing the command:

dir /x

If I remember correctly.  I do not have a windows machine.

It is a version of `bash` shell though, so you should be able to simply quote it.  (And the `dir /x` may or may not work.)

Comment: There is no `dir /x` in `bash`

Comment: No, but there is in Windows.  In other words, just because you are using the bash shell in Windows doesn't mean that you don't have access to the commands available to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are at the a directory and wanna switch to sub directory use :

```
cd "project name"
```

If you wanna go to a different path use the whole path :

```
cd "C:/Users/myname/project name"
```

> But you can avoid use white spaces in project files and folders and instead use underscore

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that worked for me (Windows 10 x64) is putting the full address in quotes:

```
cd "D:\BWayne\Documents\- School\Developer\-- Backend\Test for GitBash"
```

I could then do like `mkdir`, `touch`, etc and it successfully put them in the `Test for GitBash` folder.

Comment: sir, can you please elaborate more