# How do I install Git for Windows software to a specific directory?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I have just downloaded the latest Git for Windows installer, v2.4.  It appears to *want* to install to the standard Windows "Program files" (with-spaces-in-name) directory.

Since I have all my development code in a folder called (*simply*) "`/bin`" -- I want to see if there's a command line option or parameter to change the install directory.

In my case, these days I use a environment variable such as `GIT_HOME` for important software like git; so it would be useful if there was a way to apply that to things like git commands, etc once I have the program installed.

*possibly* related:

- [How do I change the directory in Git Bash with Git for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288723/how-do-i-change-the-directory-in-git-bash-with-git-for-windows)

I also came across a few questions asking: "*whereis* `git`".  That's answered above, however I take that as an indicator that others may want git somewhere else too.

Comment: The installation location of Git does not have much effect on how you use it.  What is your motivation for changing the default install location?

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen ... I have two points in answer, beyond the clear _motive_ expressed int the question it self: (a) the tools are in their own partition on SSD -- fast load, side-by-side installation for some, *simple *packaging* and handling.  Also, (b) I find it funny to see *talk* about user-stories and still the predictable first comment, even 51 years since Levine **Marketing Myopia** (1960), is "Why do users want '`product`' to work for-them?"  I'm licensed to share that observation, because I'm a *user-centric*.  Things I do ask, are: safe, secure, private, etc.  User questions.

Comment: Your comment belongs below my answer actually.  In any case, the Git bash is weird insofar as when it starts up in the install directory, it behaves as if it is in the root of its own mini file system, yet it is possible to change to the C: drive.  But hopefully my answer will let you continue your work without further delay.

Comment: Sorry, the author name is: Levitt, "[Marketing Myopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketing_myopia)" (1960).

Comment: VSCode allow us to sync our settings accros multiple workstations and the Git path is part of the synced settings. Currently, the default Git installation folder on Windows is AppData, which may varies depending of the username. So, beeing able to chose the installation path allow us to ensure an uniforme location acros workstations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To start the installer with a different installation path you can open a CMD terminal in the same directory as the installer executable and pass in an option parameter of `/DIR="x:\dirname"`

For instance, if you have version 2.17.0 for Windows 64bit and you want to install git to D:\git, you would run:

```
Git-2.17.0-64-bit.exe /DIR="D:\git"
```

The installer will launch as usual and you need to walk through the other options, but the install location will be the path specified.

Comment: I remmember that we were able to chose the install folder in the installation program, but this option is no longer available in newer version of the installation program. Your workaround helped, thank you very much.

Comment: It is baffling why this is not part of the installer itself...

Answer (score 2):

Since I just ran into this problem because my SSD is filling up, I figured I'd share the solution I came to on Windows 11 with Git v. 2.37.2.

The best way I could figure was to uninstall Git, then in CMD Prompt use the suggested command from the Git website with an appended `--location/ -l` flag:

```
winget install --id Git.Git -e --source winget --location [drive:/directory]
```

where `[drive:/directory]` is your target for the install. Had no issues and verified it worked with a project.